# Search Array for strings and return matches^

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with names of employees such as.

```
var names = ['Jordan,Michael','Davis,Jordan','Franco,James','Rogen,Seth','Griffin,Peter','James,Tim',..]
```

I would like to add a feature to my webpage to allow the user to type in the name they are looking for and be able to see everyone with that name. So if the user typed in Jordan. Both Jordan,Michael and Davis,Jordan would return.

Is there a way that I can do this with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes you can do this.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `var matches = result.filter(e => e.indexOf('Jordan') !== -1);`

Comment: @Grumpy Very short answer :)

Comment: the idea is that they try some coding themselves. Looks like its holiday season and some people have to proof something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**Array.prototype.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var search = 'Jordan';
var names = ['Jordan,Michael','Davis,Jordan','Franco,James','Rogen,Seth','Griffin,Peter','James,Tim']

var results = names.filter(name => name.indexOf(search) > -1);
console.log(results);
```

---

For case in-sensitive match, you need to use regex.

**The following code snippet assumes that there are only alpha-numeric characters in both *needle* and *haystack*.**<sup>The special characters can be removed by using a simple replace, `str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');`</sup>

**Note:** To allow special characters, they need to be escaped.

```js
var names = ['Jordan,Michael','Davis,Jordan','Franco,James','Rogen,Seth','Griffin,Peter','James,Tim']

var search = 'jorDan' // cAsE-InsEnsItIvE
    regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');

var results = names.filter(name => regex.test(name));
console.log(results);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: For case in-sensitive matches, use regex with `i` flag.

Comment: @Tushar, ah, yes, that would be a nice add-on :-)

Comment: @Tushar  could you add the RegEx to the example? I am not that familiar with regular expressions

Comment: @JordanDavis, like `var results = names.filter(name => name.match(new RegExp(search, 'i')));`

Comment: AmmarCSE Use `test` just to check if string contain a pattern, use `match` only when you need to extract strings matching pattern. @JordanDavis Check updated answer.

Comment: @Tushar, thanks for the edit. Man I need to stop being lazy! ;-)

Comment: @AmmarCSE does this function have a problem running in IE? when I run the first answer in IE I get a syntax error, however it works fine in chrome

Comment: @JordanDavis, yeah I just tried it in IE11 and , yes, I get a syntax error. Probably something that has to do with ES6 support in IE. Try this pre-ES6 syntax `var results = names.filter(function(name){ return  name.indexOf(search) > -1;})`

Comment: and just for documentation to use the regex answer use. var results = names.filter(function(name){ return regex.test(name);})

Answer (score 1):

Try having an array of objects like this:

```
var names = [
  {firstName:'Jordan', lastName:'Michael'},
  {firstName:'Davis', lastName:'Jordan'},
] 

var searchedName = "Jordan";
var result = names.filter(function( searchedName) {
    return names.firstName == searchedName || names.lastName == searchedName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fuzzy search field, I couldn't think of any names so this one has three Tims to illustrate the point.

It uses a Regular expression to match the letters currently being typed into the input field.

```js
var names = [
  'Jordan,Michael', 
  'Davis,Jordan', 
  'Franco,James', 
  'Rogen,Seth', 
  'Griffin,Peter', 
  'James,Tim',
  'Burton,Tim',
  'Allen,Tim'
];

var
  input = document.querySelector('#input'),
  results = document.querySelector('#results');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  filterNames( this.value );
});

// init the filter;
filterNames('');

// helper to filter the names array by a value
function filterNames( value ){
  results.innerHTML = names.filter(function(name) {
    return name.match(new RegExp( value.split('').join('.*'), 'ig'));
  }).reduce(function( str, name) {
    return str + '<li>' + name + '</li>';
  }, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<ul id="results"></ul>
```